# Relation Database Design for Friends List / Buddy List Speed

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am quickly putting together a buddy / friends list where a user will have a list of buddies. I will be be using a relation database for this and found the following post:

[Buddy List: Relational Database Table Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058281/buddy-list-relational-database-table-design)

So the buddy table might look something like this:

```
buddy_id     username
1            George
2            Henry
3            Jody
4            Cara
```

And the table for user's buddy lists would look something like this:

```
user_id      buddy_id
2            4
1            4
1            3
```

My question is how fast would it be if a user had 20,000+ buddies and wanted to pull there entire list in under a second or so. I would be running this on a pretty typical MySql setup. Would there be any key optimizations or db configurations to get this fast?

Comment: Did you consider loading some test data?

Comment: Yeah, thats option #2 but seemed like someone might have some experience with a similar layout.

Comment: Loading test data should be option #1.

Answer (score 0):

What does "pull their entire list" mean to you?

I can select 20,000 rows from a large "buddy" table (few million rows) in 15 milliseconds on my computer, but that doesn't include network transit time (both directions), formatting, and displaying on a web page. (Which I presume is the point--a web application.)

You'll need an index that covers user_id, but creating a primary key on (user_id, buddy_id) should do that.

Scripting languages are useful for generating test data. I'm using [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) today.

Comment: pulling list means I could query for user_id 1 lets say and it would return Jody, Cara so it does a join (doesn't only return the buddy_id)